# How to make an animated navbar?

Tags: animation, uinavigationcontroller, navbar, nav

I want to create an animated navbar where if I click on the hamburger menu bar then the bar including all element will animate and show some effect. How can I implement this?

Comment: there is a lot of video on youtube about this, just search it. here is one: https://youtu.be/HbBMp6yUXO0

Answer (score 0):

This Example set opacity to an element dynamically, i hope you will understand the basics.

```js
function setOpacity(element) {
    let opacity = parseInt(element.style.opacity);
    element.style.opacity = opacity;
    setInterval(() => {
        opacity = opacity + 0.1;
        element.style.opacity = opacity;
    }, 50);
}
```